# What does File.Contents take as argument in VBA to load a CSV file?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to load a CSV file in new worksheet every time I click in the corresponding cell containing the name of the file.

To do so, I used Macro Recorder. Then, I tried to change the name of the file I gave during the record to a generic variable.

The problem is I can't figure out what to give to
`CSV.Document(File.Contents(""blablabla""))` as entry. I thought it was the path of the file, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String
sFile = "file_XX"
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
sPath = sPath & "\" & sFile & ".csv"
MsgBox sPath

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=sFile, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(sPath),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=13, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=file_XX Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [file_XX]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False
    .ListObject.DisplayName = sFile
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

In other words, instead of ""root\MyFolder\file_XX.csv"" I directly replaced by sPath, and I got an Expression Error 1004. I was expecting the same results as the Macro.

What type of variable does this function expect?

Comment: Have you tried changing `File.Contents(sPath)` to `File.Contents(""" & sPath & """)` ?

Comment: You need to split out the path like this `"File.Contents(" & sPath & "),[Delimiter"...`

Comment: Thank you so much both of you Mistella and Brian M Stanfford. It works perfectly. For this problem, I used Mistella's Solution and for the other occurences of file_XX  (after Location and after FROM in the code) I used Brian's proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line ---> Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(sPath)

With Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & sPath & """)